# R sum element by element resulting in vector

Tags: r, vector, sum

First of all sorry for this question. I suppose it's super basic but I can't find the right search terms. For a vector a lets say:

```
    a<-c(1,1,3,2,1)
```

I want to get a vector b which results when suming element by element

```
    >b
    1 2 5 7 8
```

it would be something like:

```
    x<-2
    b<-as.vector(a[1])
    while(x<=length(a)) {
      c<-a[x]+b[x-1]
      b=c(b,c)
      x=x+1
    }
    rm(x,c)
```

but isn't there a built-in function for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `cumsum`:

```
a = c(1,1,3,2,1)

R> cumsum(a)
[1] 1 2 5 7 8
```